# how to resolve Error: Library doesn't support null safety. // @dart = 2.9

Tags: flutter, dart, null-safety

The language version must be >=2.12.0.  error in flutter
I am receiving the following error in the line // @dart=2.9
My dart version is 3.0.3
I am receiving this error due to which my application is not running
Earlier this was working fine now the same line of code is giving error in all my projects

Comment: share your yaml config.

Comment: environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
flutter_localizations:
  sdk: flutter
  intl: 0.17.0
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

Comment: try updating your intl package. it's old https://pub.dev/packages/intl/versions/0.17.0-nullsafety to latest https://pub.dev/packages/intl package.

Comment: the new version of intl is not supporting the rest of packages that i have used

Comment: Try using intl 18.0.0 instead of 18.0.1 and also upgrade other packages.

Comment: Tried that as well. Did not work. Error is still there

Comment: flutter run --no-sound-null-safety use this command as a workaround. See if this help

Comment: Could not find an option named "no-sound-null-safety". is the error I am receiving when I run this command